# I can't install a package with error message

Tags: r

I can't install the package "biotools" with following message.
I would appreciate it if you could answer my question.

---

```
> install.packages("biotools")
also installing the dependency ‘rpanel’

installing the source packages ‘rpanel’, ‘biotools’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rpanel_1.1-4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 716333 bytes (699 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 699 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/biotools_3.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 55301 bytes (54 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 54 KB

* installing *source* package ‘rpanel’ ...
** package ‘rpanel’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTcl, ...), class = "tclObj") : 
  [tcl] can't find package BWidget.

Error : unable to load R code in package ‘rpanel’
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘rpanel’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/rpanel’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rpanel’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘rpanel’ is not available for package ‘biotools’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/library/biotools’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘biotools’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/51/tj1ztt6j3s9crhb71hl0n6qm0000gn/T/RtmpRjR4TK/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Could you give a `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: The `rpanel` package lists `BWidget` as a system dependency. Untested installation instructions: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-mac/2006-October/003301.html